# What is the purpose of jstl's c:url tag?

Tags: java, jstl

[TutorialPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_url_tag.htm) has a simple example of the `c:url` tag that looks like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<title><c:url> Tag Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="<c:url value="/jsp/index.htm"/>">TEST</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When looking at the corresponding rendering with Chrome's developer tooling it renders like this:

```
<a href="/jsp/index.htm">TEST</a>
```

So the `c:url` tag seems redundant, but I'm sure I'm missing something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As Tutorials Points says, It is for **formatting** purposes of the *URL* you put in and it can be stored in a **variable**.

Example you have this:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/test.html"/>">TEST</a>
```

if you click **TEST**, it will go to page `test.html`. simple as that. but the question is, what is the value of `<c:url value="/test.html"/>` ?

are you thinking the value is only `/test.html`?

try to test it, like this:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/test.html" var="testvar" />">TEST</a> // testvar is where you put the url formatted by c:url
<c:out value="${testvar}"/> // you print what is the formatted url
```

the answer will be the **Context Folder** of your project plus the **URL** you put in.

*context*/test.html will be the output.

I think that its purpose is to have the `context` (Current Application) already given to the `URL`, and you only need to add the remaining `URL` part.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a short snippet from my training app where I use `<c:url>` tag:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    
    <c:forEach var="student" items="${student_list}">
    
        <c:url var="loadStudentLink" value="StudentControllerServlet">
            <c:param name="command" value="load"/>
            <c:param name="id" value="${student.id}"/>
        </c:url>
    
        <tr>
            <td> ${student.firstName} </td>
            <td> ${student.lastName} </td>
            <td> ${student.email} </td>
            <td> 
                <a href="${loadStudentLink}">Update</a>
            </td>
        </tr>   

    </c:forEach>                
</table>
```

Of course in this case I could just use the link below and it would be the same:

```
<a href="StudentControllerServlet?command=load&id=${student.id}">Update</a>
```

In a nutshell, `<c:url>` creates an ordinary link which you can store in a variable and define its scope.
With `<c:param>` tags you can set parameters for the link.
In addition, some could say that it looks more neatly with JSTL.

Also, as it was said before, `<c:url>` already has context path of the app.
So, for instance, you can do this
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/test.css"/>" />`

instead of that
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/test.css" />`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the purposes already mentioned in the other answers an additional purpose of the `c:url` tag is to rewrite URLs returned from a JSP page. For example for session tracking. In case the user agent does not support (or has disabled) cookies the jsessionid will be appended to the URL.

> The tag includes the session ID in the URL only if cookies are disabled; otherwise, it returns the URL unchanged.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html#bnakn