# Java servlets - navigate to page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have the following project structure:

[image]

I am trying to navigate to *concerts.jsp* from *index.jsp*:

*index.jsp*

```
<li class="active"><a href="/ConcertsController">Concerts</a></li>
```

This is my ConcertsController:

```
@WebServlet("/ConcertsController")
public class ConcertsController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ConcertsController() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/concerts.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
        ...
    }
```

When I run the app, and click on the link in *index.jsp*, *localhost:8080/ConcertsController* URL opens and I get the

> The requested resource is not available

error.

*Edit 1:* I am using Tomcat v7.0, servlets v3.0 and Java 8.

*Edit 2 (possible duplicate):* Well, surely I need to be able to do this without using the jstl library.

*Edit 3:* When *localhost:8080/ConcertsController* opens, I get the "resource not found" error. But when I manually edit the url to *localhost:8080/AppName/ConcertsController*, it works.

Comment: Can you confirm if doGet method is called?

Comment: @SpringLearner It's not.

Comment: can you tell us which tomcat and which servlet versions you are using?

Comment: @SpringLearner I edited my question, also, I made a mistake - the url navigated to is *localhost:8080/ConcertsController* (without the app name).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of jstl's c:url tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456615/what-is-the-purpose-of-jstls-curl-tag)

Comment: @Eutherpy I have added an answer, see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL  `localhost:8080/ConcertsController` means Application name is `ConcertsController`, port number is `8080` and the application is run locally. But you do not have `ConcertsController` Application.
so you are getting error

> The requested resource is not available

There are 2 solutions

1. if you are not using JSTL.

Change `<a href="/ConcertsController">` to `<a href="<%${pageContext.request.contextPath}%>/ConcertsController">`

2. If JSTL is used then `<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />`
   and then 
   change `<a href="/ConcertsController"> to <a href="${contextPath}/ConcertsController">`

Comment: @Eutherpy Glad, it helped

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
           <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ConcertsController">
```

Also when forwarding the request to cencerts.jsp use ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher(....)

ServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher() method will evaluate the path relative to the path of the request. But for the method of ServletContext, the path parameter cannot be relative and must start with /( / means at the root of web application not current relative path).

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/concerts.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

instead of:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pages/concerts.jsp").forward(request, response);
```